# A generalization of Clausen's formula

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request, power-series, hypergeometric-function

Clausen's formula,
$${}_{2}F_{1}(a, b; c; x)^2 = {}_{3}F_{2}(2a, 2b, a + b; 2a + 2b, c; x), \quad c = a + b + \frac{1}{2},$$
is well known. Does anyone know if this formula has been generalized for an arbitrary $c$?

Comment: There is an identity due to Caley and Orr http://mathworld.wolfram.com/OrrsTheorem.html and also the following for arbitrary $c$ due to Bailey ${}_2F_1(a,b,c,z){}_2F_1(a,b,a+b-c+1,z)={}_4F_3(a,b,(a+b)/2,(a+b+1)/2;c,a+b,a+b-c+1;4z(1-z))$.